# Python searches CSV for string in one column, returns string from another column in the same row

Tags: python, string, csv, search

I'm attempting to write a program in python that searches ~27,000 rows for each string in a list. Each string I am searching for is in one column, and has an 'id' value in another column that I would like printed if found. The code I currently have counts the number of times that string appears in the document, but I am still unable to find a way to return specific values for each unique row in which the strings are found.

```
import csv
fin = open('data.csv')
words = ["happy","sad","good","bad","sunny","rainy"]
found = {}
count = 0
for line in fin:
    for word in words:
        if word in line:
            count = count + 1
    found[word] = count
print(found)
```

The main semantic problem with the code above is that printing the 'found' dictionary only yields one of the results and its count from the 'words' list.

Answer (score 2):

For something like this, I think using the `pandas` library will keep your sanity in check. Assuming a 15,000-row CSV file with two columns, `String` and `ID`.

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: words = ['happy','sad','good','bad','sunny','rainy']

In [3]: df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

In [4]: df.head(5)
Out[4]: 
  Strings  ID
0   happy   1
1     sad   2
2   happy   3
3     sad   4
4    good   5

In [5]: for word in words:
   ...:     print '{} : {}'.format(word, df['Strings'].str.lower().str.contains(word).sum())
   ...:     
happy : 2501
sad : 2500
good : 2500
bad : 2500
sunny : 2499
rainy : 2500
```

Alternatively, you can just create a pivot table and it will have similar results.

```
In [30]: df_pt = df.pivot_table(index='Strings',values='ID',aggfunc=len)

In [31]: df_pt
Out[31]: 
Strings
bad        2500
good       2500
happy      2501
rainy      2500
sad        2500
sunny      2499
Name: ID, dtype: int64
```

If you need to get the IDs for each word, you can just simply select/index/filter the data:

```
In [6]: df_happy = df[df['Strings'] == 'happy']

In [7]: df_happy.head(5)
Out[7]: 
   Strings  ID
0    happy   1
2    happy   3
12   happy  13
14   happy  15
18   happy  19
```

If you need it as a list, then:

```
In [8]: list_happy = df_happy['ID'].tolist()

In [9]: list_happy[:5]
Out[9]: [1, 3, 13, 15, 19]
```

I've truncated some parts, obviously, but the idea remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

You said that you would like to print the id of the row when you found a word. Assuming that you have a comma separated csv file with only two colums, this is how I would do it:

```
fin = open('data.csv')
words = ["happy","sad","good","bad","sunny","rainy"]
found = {}
for line in fin:
    str1,id=line.split(',')
    for w in words:
        if w in str1:
            print id
            found[w]=found.get(w,0)+1
            break

print(found)
```

If you have multiple columns in the file, you could instead do:

```
split_line=line.split(',')
str1=split_line[0] # Whatever columns
id=split_line[1] # Whatever columns
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for line in fin: # loops over the lines of the file
    for word in words: # loops over your word list
        if word in line: # checks if current word is in line
            count = count + 1 # increments global variable "count". Everytime a word in the list is found in the line. With no reset or save-away inbetween whatsoever. This is the number of times any word appears in any line at the end.
    found[word] = count # assigns - after all words are looped over - current "count" value to found[current_word]
```

so what you are doing is assigning an arbitrary value to a dictionary key which happens to be the last word you check for in every iteration.

Does not seem very useful to me. I guess you intended to do something like:

```
from collections import defaultdict
found = defaultdict(int)
for line in fin:
    for word in words:
        if word in line:
           found[word] += 1
```

Comment: Awesome. I'm still a novice in Python, so thanks for the added comments and solution. This solves the counting problem, but how can I return the 'id' value I mentioned for each row that 'word' is found in?

Comment: Well, you'd have to keep track of the id's. Just store them away, as you find them.